# Why is my output value in exponential format 1.04e+05?

Tags: matlab, numbers, number-formatting

I am calculating the area of objects in my image using `bwarea` like so:

```
i=imread('Z:\Azhagu project work\MRI\input.jpg');
imshow(i);    
bwarea(i)
```

This gives the following output:

```
ans = 1.0428e+05
```

Why is the area in an exponential format?

Comment: Are you wanting to display the answer or do more calculations to it? If you want to do more calculations, it is probably best keeping it in that format.

Comment: @TomDee there is no "that format". You can not change it. You can only change the way its displayed, but that wont change the number

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191571/why-did-matlab-delete-my-decimals

Comment: Not sure why this question is accumulating downvotes when the canonical version [subsequently asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191571/why-did-matlab-delete-my-decimals) by @Adriaan is accumulating upvotes? Yeah it was poorly formatted, but essentially the main difference is the OP didn't know what they were asking about, which is why they were asking. Azhagu: please read [ask] so you can write more descriptive questions in future.

Comment: @Wolfie probably because this is a very basic mistake, which shows that the fundamentals of MATLAB haven't been understood, which leads to the conclusion that this question is "not well researched", and that's what the tooltip on the downvote arrow says. I guess my question's upvoted because I wrote a canonical Q/A, and people thinking the answer good might've dropped a vote on the question as well. (I decided to write a separate question since the image-relation is irrelevant to the general cause here)

Answer (score 4):

It's not in exponential output; it's in scientific notation.

```
ans = 1.0428e+05 == 104280
```

You can force MATLAB to show all decimals using `format long` or `format longG`. This is just a display quirk of MATLAB, internally your number is stored as a `double` anyway, so for further calculations this is of no concern.

Answer (score 1):

This area value is not in exponential format. For your given image, area is represented in Floating-Point numbers format. Hence the value **1.0428e+05** is actually **104280**.